# IIS Metabase Explorer for IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

We have many IIS7.5 web servers which require support from different departments and we would like to avoid giving away too many privileges to certain user groups (security groups in Active Directory).

We would like to take a backup of the IIS configuration, store it in one location for all servers and allow those support units to read/view the configuration instead of accessing the IIS administrative tools directly from each server.

I was thinking of Metabase Explorer which used to be available for IIS 6.0 in Resource Kit. Is there something similar that users can install to their workstations to view the IIS config from different servers?

Or is there a better way to give a security group read only access to IIS configuration on servers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about IIS administration. Probably better on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.iis.net/configreference

Simply copy the applicationHost.config file (along with other XML files necessary). Metabase Explorer is obsolete and should be avoided to be used against IIS 7 and above.

IIS 7 and above does introduce better remote administration support, which you can learn from http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7

Please treat it seriously as a brand new product, or your IIS 6 knowledge might mislead you.